# Is my CPL faulty?

Tags: filters, polarizer

I recently a got a CPL filter for my camera. It is manufactured by a company called Massa. I tired playing around with it but never figured it out. The only thing it is does is make my photo yellowish. Is my filter broken?

Comment: Yes I had read that and tried it, but my CPL doesn't seem to work that way at all.

Comment: What did you want to achieve with your filter? And how did you try to achieve this?

Comment: I tried enhancing the color of the sky, tried to make the leaves look better when under direct sunlight and tried to remove the reflection. But, when I turn the filter, the photo becomes a bit yellowish and that's it. Is it normal for the CPL to give a yellow tinge?

Here is a [link](http://i.imgur.com/Of6s1x7.gif) where I have kept the CPL in front of a white screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the GIf you've linked to is showing you turning the filter in front of an Laptop LCD screen.

There are simply too many optical things going on there for the 'yellowing' effect to be caused by the filter. You'd need to understand exactly how your particular LCD screen works, but I too see a slight yellowing at certain angles when rotating a polarizer in front of a Macbook screen.

In short, from your GIF, your filter is working correctly. Take some outdoor shots looking into running water, and rotate the CPL as you do so. That will show you how it can kill or modify reflections.

Massa filters do seem to be dirt cheap, so I wouldn't expect the same build (or image) quality as say, Tiffen or Hoya - but it should be good enough for you to learn with.

Comment: I was afraid my CPL was faulty because I read online in many sites that the filter should not give any color change to the image. I am going on a trip next week and I will try to use it more. Once I get the hang of it, I'll try to upgrade to a better one. Thank you.

Comment: For details of how LCDs work (and how they use polarizing filters internally) see here. This wil explain why you see odd interactions between an LCD and your CPL. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display

Comment: Aakassh, I wouldn't say your filter is faulty *per se*, but if it gives a very noticeable color-cast, it is not high quality.

Answer (score 2):

CPL filters only work properly when viewed from the correct side (the side which attaches to the camera). If you look through them from the opposite side they do indeed produce a yellowing effect and very little polarisation.  Perhaps you're looking through it the wrong way around? Perhaps it's been mounted the wrong way around during manufacture?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Put it on your camera lens
Step 2: While looking through the viewfinder rotate the filter until it gives you the effect you desire
Step 3: Take the picture
Step 4: If the filter adds any color cast, you can usually correct this very easily in post-processing, especially if you are working with raw files.

Be aware that if the front of your lens moves when zooming or focusing you will need to insure the filter doesn't also rotated after you have set it to the desired effect.

Due to the way LCD monitors polarize light, there will be some strange effects when you look at your monitor through a polarizing filter.